# Java classpath wildcard not working without quotes

Tags: java, classpath

I have a folder with lots of jar files and a classpath:

```
-classpath ./classes:./jogamp-all-platforms/jar/*
```

But it doesn't find the package. Just to make sure that I have the resource in question I manually find the jar that contains it and change the classpath to:

```
-classpath ./classes:./jogamp-all-platforms/jar/jogl-all.jar
```

And now it isn't complaining about not finding a package.

Comment: what do you get when you run `java -version`?

Comment: I got 1.6 something, checking... 1.6.0_24

Comment: I mean of course I got a late enough version to have wildcards, wern't they added like a long time ago?

Comment: Just to verify if you are using the wrong jdk. I have 3 jdks installed and often run into such problems

Answer (score 2):

Under Debian I had to put quotations marks just around the wildcard for this to work: `"*"`

Then the compile command becomes:

```
javac -cp ~/my\ stuff/Java/"*" test.java
```

I'm using JDK, JRE 8.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `*` is expanded to all the entries in your directory and the classpath syntax allows directories and jar files separated with `:` on your platform. `*` is expanded and will include all the jars in your directory and you will end with something like:

`-classpath ./classes:./jogamp-all-platforms/jar/jogl-all.jar another.jar etc.jar`

If in your `./jogamp-all-platforms/` directory you have the `jogl-all.jar` `another.jar` `etc.jar` jars.

You can escape the `*` expansion by the shell using something like:

`-classpath './classes:./jogamp-all-platforms/jar/*'`

This way your compiler will interpret the `*` expansion.

Comment: When is it expanded and by whom? You don't mean to say the shell expands it before sending it to the compiler do you? I'm confused.

Comment: @DudeDawg `*` is expanded by the shell, before sending to the compiler. You can insert an `echo` before your command to see how everything is expanded.

Comment: @DudeDawg see my updated answer on how to escape the expansion by the shell

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use `;` as path separator after `./classes` as below:

```
 -classpath ./classes;./jogamp-all-platforms/jar/*
```

**Also please note:**

`Subdirectories are not searched recursively. For example, jogamp-all-platforms/jar/* looks for JAR/Class files only in jogamp-all-platforms/jar, not in jogamp-all-platforms/jar/abcd, jogamp-all-platforms/jar/efc, etc.`

By doing `-classpath ./classes:./jogamp-all-platforms/jar/*`, it looks of all the JARs in `jogamp-all-platforms/jar` folder only.

For more details, please refer the documentation here- [**Wildcards in classpath**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

Comment: @DudeDawg: Just to let you know that I updated the answer. Please check, if that is helpful.

Comment: I also tried using both ; and , as separators, but still no luck.

Comment: @DudeDawg: Please refer the documentation here- [Wild cards in classpath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html).

Comment: Semicolon only used in Windows for separating path elements. Pretty much every other platform uses a colon.

Answer (score 0):

The first form will not work.  You cannot load jar files with wildcards.  The second form should work, unless you're missing dependent classes.

Comment: It's a new feature they added, wildcards can be used to load jars. Except it isn't actually working.

Comment: @DudeDawg It's working but in your case the `*` was expanded by the shell, you need to escape that, see my updated answer.